# How to calculate Category Utility

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, classification, decision-tree

I am currently trying to implement Category Utility (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_utility#Probability-theoretic_definition_of_category_utility)) in Python. I am trying to use Pandas to accomplish this. I have a rough draft of code currently, however I am pretty sure that it's wrong. I think it's wrong specifically in the code that deals with looping over the clusters and calculating the `inner_sum`, seeing as Category Utility requires going through all possible values for each attribute. Would anyone be able to help me figure out how to improve this draft such that it properly calculates the category utility for the given clusters?

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import List

def probability(df: pd.DataFrame, clause: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Gets the probabilities of the values within the given data frame
    of the provided clause
    """
    return df.groupby(clause).size().div(len(df))


def conditional_probability(df: pd.DataFrame, clause: str, given: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Gets the conditional probability of the values within the provided data
    frame of the provided clause assuming that the given is true.
    """
    base_probabilities: pd.DataFrame = probability(df, clause=given)
    return df.groupby([clause, given]).size().div(len(df))
        .div(base_probabilities, axis=0, level=given)

def category_utility(clusters: pd.DataFrame) -> float:
    # k is the number of clusters.
    k: int = len(clusters)
    # probabilities of all clusters. To be used to get P(C_l)
    probs_of_clusters: pd.DataFrame = probability(clusters, 'clusters')
    # probabilities of all attributes being any possible value.
    # To be used to get P(a_i = v_ij)
    probs_of_attr_vals: pd.DataFrame = probability(clusters, 'attributes')
    # Probabilities of all attributes being any possible value given the cluster they're in.
    # To be used to get P(a_i = v_ij | C_l) 
    cond_prob_of_attr_vals: pd.DataFrame = conditional_probability(clusters, clause='attributes', given='clusters')

    tracked_cu: List[float] = []

    for cluster in clusters['clusters']:
        # The probability of the current cluster.
        # P(C_l)
        prob_of_curr_cluster: float = probs_of_clusters[cluster]
        # The summation of the square difference between an attribute being in a cluster and just overall existing in the data.
        # E (P(a_i = v_ij | C_l) ^ 2 - P(a_i = v_ij) ^ 2)
        inner_sum: float = sum([cond_prob_of_attr_vals[attr] ** 2 - probs_of_attr_vals[attr] for attr in clusters['attributes']])

        tracked_cu += inner_sum * prob_of_curr_cluster
    return sum(tracked_cu) / k
```

Any help with correctly implementing this would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide details on what you think is wrong?

Comment: Yes. I believe that I'm likely not understanding how to compute the inner sum and likely things surrounding it. The pandas I'm sure is also wrong, but I believe that'll just mean I need to look it up on my own.

Comment: Try to come up with a concise question. Right now it is a bit broad

Comment: Alright I will edit my question. Thank you.